# Python Request Stream

Tags: python, request, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape a website that seems to dynamically downloads some data to the website. I want to scrape.

The website starts with:

```
<td class="border_TopRight border_Left">
    Text - "TEST_NAME
<td class="border_TopRight">
    Text - TEST_NAME_1
<td class="border_TopRight">
    Text - TEST_NAME_2
<td class="apple dataCell border_TopRight font_green" id="Number of Apples" style="color: #333333; background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);" rel="Apples ">
    Text - '-'
```

Then the website will load information in as:

```
<td class="border_TopRight border_Left">
        Text - "TEST_NAME
    <td class="border_TopRight">
        Text - TEST_NAME_1
    <td class="border_TopRight">
        Text - TEST_NAME_2
    <td class="apple dataCell border_TopRight font_green" id="Number of Apples" style="color: #333333; background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);" rel="Apples ">
        Text - '999999.99'
```

I am trying to use Python request and stream to get the data after it loads, but I am not having much success.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

tarball_url = xxxxx
r = requests.get(tarball_url, stream=True)

soup = BeautifulSoup(r)

td = soup.findAll('td')

for line in td:
    print(str(line.get_text()))
```

This Returns:

```
TEST_NAME
TEST_NAME_1
TEST_NAME_2
 -
```

Is there a way I can scrape the data after the website updates the datacell? It is normally pretty fast within a few seconds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found following link. This seems to work great for me.

http://koaning.github.io/html/scapingdynamicwebsites.html